JsonPath returned wrong value in multiple threads
I did sample code below to check JsonPath version 2.9.0 thread safe or not, I realized it did not.
Is that the issue of JsonPath or there is any way to cope it? Or any alternative solution? Please help
@Test
  public void testJsonPath() throws IOException {

    String jsonString = "{\"test\":1,\"person\":{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":50}}";
    String jsonString2 ="{\"test\":1,\"person\":{\"name\":\"Babara\",\"age\":48}}";
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(createRunnable(jsonString));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(createRunnable(jsonString2));
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    try {
      thread1.join();
      thread2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private Runnable createRunnable(String json) {
    return () -> {
      int count = 10;
      try {
        while (count > 0) {
          count--;
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          String value = JsonPath.read(json, "concat($.person.name, $.person.age)");
          if (value.equals("John48") || value.equals("Babara50")) {
            System.out.println("Wrong value returned: " + value);
          }
          System.out.printf("Thread-[%d], Value: [%s]%n", Thread.currentThread().getId(), value);

        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    };
  }

The result showed that JsonPath return wrong values, such as: Babara50, John48
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]
Thread-[31], Value: [Babara48]
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]
Thread-[31], Value: [Babara48]
Thread-[31], Value: [Babara48]
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]
Thread-[31], Value: [Babara48]
Thread-[30], Value: [**Babara50**]
Thread-[31], Value: [**John48**]
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]
Thread-[31], Value: [Babara48]
Thread-[30], Value: [**Babara50**]
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]
Thread-[31], Value: [**John48**]
Thread-[31], Value: [**John48**]
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]
Thread-[31], Value: [Babara48]
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]
Thread-[31], Value: [Babara48]
Thread-[30], Value: [John50]


Your example has nothing to do with thread safety you are reading a passing value  and threads are not updating same value. You are just reading. Also i cant reproduce you behaviour. Are you doing any extra magic ? I would add if (value == "John48") and put breakpoint inside. I feel there is more to your example then you posted

updated the code to print wrong values returned

I can reproduce this, and I don't think you're doing anything obviously wrong.

Looks like you are hitting a bug https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/975

This is caused by this bug https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/975 as Vova Bilychat pointed out in a comment on the question.
The jayway JsonPath  implementation uses a cache which is maintained across calls to JsonPath.read.
You can disable the cache by setting a dummy cache which never finds anything:
CacheProvider.setCache(new NOOPCache());


Thanks, also notice that there is a provided implementation to disable cache             CacheProvider.setCache(new NOOPCache());
